# Custom slug in url for CPT and taxonomy

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to add a custom slug to permalink for CPT and taxonomy.
Like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/my-custom-slug/post-slug
http://mydomain.com/my-custom-slug/product_category
```

Here is my CPT and taxonomy code:

```
$args = array(
    'query_var'           => 'product',
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'my-custom-slug'),
);
register_post_type( 'product', $args );
```

This above CPT `product` output desired permalink,

```
http://mydomain.com/my-custom-slug/post-slug
```

but it give error 404.

and same thing happen with taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('product_category', array('product'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'my-custom-slug', 'hierarchical' => false, 'with_front' => false)
));
```

please tell me how do I fix this.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you register cpt and taxonomies, remove the `rewrite` argument completely (use the default) and then go to your dashboard, and from *Settings > Permalinks* set permalink structure to (*Custom Structure*) and type

```
/my-custom-slug/%postname%
```

Screenshots:

---

The setting:

[image]

---

The result:

[image]

---

save changes, and everything should be just like you want.

Comment: not working, it output: `http://mydomain.com/my-custom-slug/%postname%/post-slug`

Comment: Are you sure have you setted everything correctly? (see screenshot I added to answer). `%postname%` is a rewrite tag embedded in WordPress, not a custom one (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags), so it should *always* work. Double check, and if problem persist try to disable your plugin, switch to default theme and try again... @user1983017

Comment: Thanks for answer it was helpful, but I want to achieve this from code, not from setting. cuz I want this rewrite rule for a plugin I am working. Thanks for understanding.